# cocoapods not updating a repository correctly

Tags: ios, github, cocoapods, podspec

While updating my project, which contains this line in the `Podfile`:

```
pod 'UIView-Autolayout', :git => 'https://github.com/dkk/UIView-Autolayout.git'
```

with the command `pod update` I want to update [the pod in this github repository](https://github.com/dkk/UIView-Autolayout), which has following podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = 'UIView-Autolayout'
  s.version      = '0.2.2'
  s.license      = 'MIT'
  s.platform     = :ios, '6.0'

  s.summary      = 'Category on UIView to simplify the creation of common layout constraints.'
  s.homepage     = 'https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout'
  s.author       = { 'Richard Turton' => 'jrturton@gmail.com' }
  s.source       = { :git => 'https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.source_files = 'Source/*.{h,m}'

  s.requires_arc = true
end
```

As output I get: `Installing UIView-Autolayout 0.2.1 (was 0.2.1)`. Why does it not install version `0.2.2`??

(My project is iOS7.0, with ARC)

If I replace the `Podfile` line with `pod 'UIView-Autolayout', :git => 'https://github.com/dkk/UIView-Autolayout.git', '0.2.2'` I get an error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That repo doesn't have a tag for version `0.2.2` it won't update until the developer / contributor adds a tag.

Cocoapods uses this value:

```
s.version      = '0.2.2'
```

by looking for a tag name that matches the string exactly.

**EDIT**

The source will also need to point to your repo:

```
s.source       = { :git => 'https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
```

**EDIT 2**

It seems commenting out the pod (placing a hash at the beginning of the line) and running pod install (to remove it), then uncommenting and running pod install again was necessary.

Gut feeling is that the pods.lock file had something cached and didn't want to switch to a new repo for the same library.

Comment: I added a tag called [0.2.2](https://github.com/dkk/UIView-Autolayout/releases/tag/0.2.2), but I''m still getting the wrong version

Comment: I changed the line to `s.source  = { :git => 'https://github.com/dkk/UIView-Autolayout.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }`  and set the tag 0.2.2 to the last commit, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: @simpleBob are you still getting the same error `Installing UIView-Autolayout 0.2.1 (was 0.2.1)`?

Comment: yes, also, it says `Pre-downloading: 'UIView-Autolayout' from 'https://github.com/dkk/UIView-Autolayout.git', commit '111dd0f4572e562802fea3b06d7168849a7e3e0d'`, which is the wrong commit

Comment: @simpleBob It all looks right to me, only guess is maybe theres some issue with it changing repos? Maybe something is being cached in the pods.lock file. Have you tried commenting out this pod (place a hash symbol at the start of the line), running pod install. Then uncommenting it and running pod install again?

Comment: that worked! ahh, good ol' "have you tried turning it off and on again" exists for a reason :)

Comment: You are a life-saver @SimonMcLoughlin